# Human readable byte-size in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string, human-readable

How can we display a human readable byte size in python?

We need to convert large unreadable `int` results, like the ones from `os.stat(r'C:\1.pdf').st_size`

(Answering my own question below with f-strings for python versions above 3.6, please add your own answers if they apply to other python versions or other ways of formatting)

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize?

Comment: @NOhs didn't know that one, tnx for the reference

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to share this little snippet in case anyone finds it usefeul, this function converts byte-sizes (like the ones you'd get from `os.stat(r'C:\1.pdf').st_size`)

```
from typing import Union
def readable_size(size: Union[int, float, str]) -> str:
    units = ('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB')
    size_list = [f'{int(size):,} B'] + [f'{int(size) / 1024 ** (i + 1):,.1f*} {u}' for i, u in enumerate(units)]
    return [size for size in size_list if not size.startswith('0.')][-1]
```

If you don't want to do `from typing import Union` just remove that type-hint from the function, this is here just to show that this function can accept `int`, `float`, and `str` arguments. A stripped down version would look like this:

```
def readable_size(size):
    units = ('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB')
    size_list = [f'{int(size):,} B'] + [f'{int(size) / 1024 ** (i + 1):,.1f*} {u}' for i, u in enumerate(units)]
    return [size for size in size_list if not size.startswith('0.')][-1]
```

**Examples:**

```
>>> import random
>>> for i in range(15):
...     size = random.randint(1 ** i, 9 ** i)
...     print(f'{size} = {readable_size(size)}')
...
1 = 1 B
3 = 3 B
61 = 61 B
267 = 267 B
5127 = 5.0 KB
37700 = 36.8 KB
68512 = 66.9 KB
342383 = 334.4 KB
42580724 = 40.6 MB
40250452 = 38.4 MB
1789601996 = 1.7 GB
16242182039 = 15.1 GB
131167506597 = 122.2 GB
1827741623713 = 1.7 TB
5613973017836 = 5.1 TB
```

Limitations: this function only lists units up to terabytes (TB), but that can easily be modified by extending the `units` tuple. Obviously this uses f-strings so only applies for python versions above 3.6